# Flutter : Not able to edit pubspec.yml file, It displays "File is read-only" popup warning while trying to edit pubspec.yml file

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to Flutter. I am trying to create one hybrid app using Flutter/Dart. I was able to edit pubspec.yml so far, but suddenly it says "File is read-only" when try to type anything in this file. Could anyone please help how can i make it editable again.

I have attached the screenshot for reference. Screenshot is captured when "File is read-only" warning is displayed on keyboard key press.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHZ0H.png)

Thanks,
Davinder

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Mac user you have to "Change permissions",  you could do so:

**Assign permissions to users and groups**

1. On your Mac, select a disk, folder, or file, then choose File > Get
   Info.
2. If the information in Sharing & Permissions isn’t visible,
       click the disclosure triangle.
3. Click the lock icon  to unlock it.
4. Enter an administrator name and password.
5. Click a user or group in the Name column, then choose a privilege setting from   the pop-up menu.

   - Read & Write: Allows a user to open the item and change it.
   - Read Only: Allows a user to open the item, but not change its
     contents.
   - Write Only: Makes a folder into a drop box. Users can copy
     items to the drop box, but can’t open it. Only the owner of the drop
     box can open it.
   - No Access: Blocks all access to the item.

[Learn more](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-permissions-for-files-folders-or-disks-mchlp1203/mac)